# Can Lion support resolutions higher than 1920 by 1200 on the retina MBP main display?

Tags: macos, resolution, macbook-pro

The new retina display MacBook Pro is advertised to have a native display resolution of 2880 by 1800. On the Lion 10.7.4 build, the system preferences limits the highhest resolution at 1920 by 1200.

Can this be raised easily in Lion? (and are there any undesirable side effects to changing this?)

Comment: I wonder what resolution the screen looks like when selecting the "More Space" side of the scaling in the Display System Preferences on the Retina MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with a little help you can get to the native resolution and a few others as well.

Have a look at: http://osxdaily.com/2012/06/18/3-ways-to-run-a-retina-macbook-pro-at-2880x1800-native-resolution/

The article mentions 4 software products that allow easy setting of the resolution without using Apple's display pane.

- SwitchResX
- SetResX
- scrutil
- ChangeResolution

Good luck reading small type, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

On new hardware, this is displayed differently than the traditional Display preferences pane. So yes, but you won't see the traditional n x n resolution listed. Here's what it will look like on a retina-enabled MacBook Pro:

[image: Display Preferences]

Comment: Will non retina external displays have traditional resolution settings on the MacBook Pro Retina?

Comment: @MrDaniel No, they don't get the traditional resolution (at least when using a Apple Display). I saw that @ the app store, where they had a Retina Mac connected to an external apple display.

Comment: More space maps to 1920 by 1200 when booted to finder and selecting more. I want more than more :-)

Answer (score 2):

What gives you the idea that Lion is restricted to 1920x1200?

[image]

Comment: Sorry - edited the question title to more closely match the request to address the retina display on the MBP.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum resolution in Lion, as in most operating systems, depends on your graphics adaptor and monitor, so the answer is different for different hardware configurations.

Comment: While generally right, this is actually incorrect for the Retina MacBook Pro. See some of the other answers for the details.

Answer (score -3):

As you know, the new Mac OS X Mountain Lion is coming and it will release before Retina MBP. That mean every Retina MBP will run Mountain Lion. You won't get Retina MBP running Lion. It's like you cannot get a "The new iPad" (iPad 3) running iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Well, I wonder what the Retina MBP is running I saw in the Apple Store on Saturday. Didn't look like Mountain Lion to me.

Comment: Did they sell the Retina MBP already? I tough they will sell it in September?

Comment: Current delivery time is 3-4 weeks but was shorter initially. And the ones in the Store are operational as well, so no ML on them.

Comment: If they run Lion on the Retina display, imagine all the icon will be half of the size and it'll look really small on the 15 inch display, if you see the same icon size on the normal and the retina display, might be they had some modified the Lion for the retina display.

Comment: A lot of icons on Lion are already at a higher resolution, that's one of the reasons the rumor about a Retina Mac has been around for a while now.

Comment: I've never work on a Mac which display more than 1440x900 display, but I see the iMac at the store the icon are really small. I don't think the the original Lion release till now support the full Retina display on MBP, might be they made big icon for experimental only. Like some big icon they found on the previous iOS version before the iPad 2 release.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: Well, this is only my thought. As my comments, I'm now not sure about my answer. Could you please state my wrong?

Comment: The retina MBP has been in customer hands since last Tuesday. Mountain Lion is not released yet and doesn't even have a ship date. The retina MBP ships with Lion 10.7.4 as I stated in the question so this doesn't seem analogous to running an iPad on older OS.